# Toolbar barbutton icon(pagecurl) not loaded

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar, page-curl

I am  loading a mapview. I have created a barbutton in the bottombar toolbar of the view, setting its identifier as pagecurl. As expected, a barbutton with page curl icon is loaded. From this mapview I move to anotherv view, by clicking on annotations in the mapview. And then I return to the mapview. At that time my pagecurl barbutton icon(pagecurl icon) is not displayed, and my barbutton width is also reduced. I am not able to figure out the problem.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(isSingleContactSelected)
    {
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.cancelButton   ;
        [self.cancelButton setTarget:self];
        [self.cancelButton setAction:@selector(onClose:)];

        [addressFieldSearchBar setFrame:CGRectMake(66, 0, 256, 44)];
        addressFieldSearchBar.delegate =self;

        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:addressFieldSearchBar];

        [searchDirectionSegmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        UIBarButtonItem *searchDirectionSegmentedButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:searchDirectionSegmentedControl];

        flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
        NSArray *toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: compassButton , flexibleSpace, searchDirectionSegmentedButton, flexibleSpace, pageButton, nil];
        [self setToolbarItems:toolbarItems];

        self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
        [compassButton release];
        [pageButton release];
        [searchDirectionSegmentedControl release];

        mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
        mapView.delegate=self; 

        [self.view addSubview:mapView]; 
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload{
    [super viewDidUnload];    
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    if(isSingleContactSelected){
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
        [self.navigationController.toolbar setHidden:NO];
        [self.navigationController.toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];
        [self.addressFieldSearchBar setHidden:NO];
    }
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    if(isSingleContactSelected){
        [self.addressFieldSearchBar setHidden:YES];
        [self.navigationController.toolbar setHidden:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the code. I set the property of the barbutton through the xib file.

Comment: move your code for setting toolbar inside `viewWillAppear:` method.

Comment: @XaviValero when you say "move to another view", do you mean a new VC is pushed into the navigation controller or just add/remove another view on the mapView?

Comment: @mr.pppoe .... A new VC is pushed

Comment: @XaviValero Have you done anything to the navigationController.toolbar in the new VC, in its viewWillAppear/viewWillDisappear. I met a similar issue in iOS 5 SDK, just want to find out whether you are in the same case.

Comment: Yes. i am loading another toolbar in the new VC. And this vc is being used multiple times in my project, and I haven't had an issue with any other views/toolbars. Its just this barbuttonitem with the page curl as identifier, which is having the problem. The rest of the buttons in the toolbar are working fine.

Comment: Are you using ARC? Have you declared the `UIBarButtonItem` with the `weak` storage qualifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though its a long shot, it could be something to do with the setHidden calls in your appear and disappear methods.

```
[self.navigationController.toolbar setHidden:YES];
[self.navigationController.toolbar setHidden:NO];
```

The best way to do this using UIViewController's "-setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:" method.

Maybe try some NSLog() in -viewWillAppear:

```
// If pageButton is an instance variable
NSLog(@"%@",pageButton);

// Enumerate through all toolbar items.
// Check to see if NSLog output differs after pushing/popping this view controller.
for (UIBarButtonItem *item in [self.navigationController.toolbar.items])
{
    NSLog(@"%@",item);
}
```

Comment: The same issue has popped up again and this time I cant handle it.

Answer (score 0):

`setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed` method did the trick in this case.